# How are third party controls exposed to "Windows Store apps" when app is written in HTML\WinJS?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winjs

How are third party controls exposed to "Windows Store apps" when app is written in HTML\JS?

Does the vendor have to provide a C#\VB.Net and WinJS version?  And if so what work is involved in doing that, is it a complete re-write (I'm kind of assuming so but want to double check)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share functionality like business logic and/or Windows Runtime access, you could create a one time component in C# and add it as a reference to your javascript project and use it as you would a regular javascript function.

When talking about UI, javascript and C# sit on top of different things. You have WinJS and HTML controls for javascript and [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700354.aspx) for C# so I don't see a way you could actually share a UI component thru the different languages.